# How to config webfonts-loader webpack module in vue cli

Tags: vue.js, webpack

Trying to add svgs as font to my project,I added this code to my vue.config file, there is no error on build and run, but there are no generated files as well,

```
module.exports = {
  assetsDir: "./static/",
  productionSourceMap: false,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
        .rule('font-icons')
        .test(/\.font\.js/)
        .use('minicssextract-loader')
        .loader(MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader)
        .end()
        .use('css-loader')
        .loader('css-loader')
        .end()
        .use('webfonts-loader')
        .loader('webfonts-loader')
        .options({
            files: [
                './src/assets/svg/*.svg'
            ],
            'fontName': 'intelosFont',
            html: true,
            'classPrefix': 'inls-',
            'baseSelector': '.inls',
            'types': ['eot', 'woff', 'woff2', 'ttf', 'svg'],
            'fileName': 'app.dfdfdf.[ext]'

        })
        .end()
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use `file-loader`

```
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "img/[name].[ext]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
```

Comment: as far as i understand this is config for file loader and not for, webfonts-loader, and this is not config via chainWebpack, or am i missing something?

Comment: I think it's same same 
`{
        test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "fonts/[name].[ext]"
          }
        }
      }`

Comment: so what is the fix ?what exactly your part of code does that mine not ?thank you